# Qt Layout on QMainWindow

Tags: qt, layout, qt-designer

I designed a `QMainWindow` with `QtCreator's` designer. It consists of the default central widget (a `QWidget`) which contains a `QVBoxLayout` with all the other widgets in it. Now everything I want, is that the `QVBoxLayout` automatically occupies the whole central widgets rectangle space.

How can I do this? I didn't find any usable property neither in the central widgets properties nor the `QVBoxLayout's` ones.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You don't have to create a `QVBoxLayout` manually. Just select your central `QWidget` and press a make-layout button.

[image]

Comment: Note that you must have at least one widget already on the central widget for the make-layout buttons to be enabled

Answer (score 83):

If you want to do it with code instead of using `QtCreator`, you could set the layout in a `QWidget` and then set the `QWidget` as the central widget of the main window like this:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow() {  

        // Set layout
        QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
        layout->addWidget(myWidget1);
        layout->addWidget(myWidget2);

        // Set layout in QWidget
        QWidget *window = new QWidget();
        window->setLayout(layout);

        // Set QWidget as the central layout of the main window
        setCentralWidget(window);

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But I don't get it ... what's the reasoning behind the introduced need to create a new widget? Wouldn't it have been more intuitive to just allow the layout to be applied to the main window?

Comment: I faced same issue. Before coming here, Logically I was trying to setLayout on QMainWindow but didn't work. Using QWidget it worked.

Comment: If `MainWindow` inherits form `QMainWindow` then you can just call `centralWidget()->setLayout(layout);`. I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251047/qt-setlayout-and-setcentralwidget)

Comment: My concern is that the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework) say `Note: Creating a main window without a central widget is not supported.` That being said, it compiles and runs for me... But I wish Qt was a little more clear about this "requirement".

Comment: How do you `delete()` the `layout` object?  Is it automatic?

Answer (score 17):

Add at least one widget on your `MainWindow`. Then select your window by clicking on it and click on the `VerticalLayout` Button at the top of `QTCreator`. You Vertical Layout is automatically added to the central widget and fills all the surface.

Comment: Thank you.  I couldn't figure it out because I didn't have any widgets on my MainWindow, so your answer was most helpful

Answer (score 3):

This is already answered, but I personally prefer to keep all control elements *and* layouts added manually to the form. I do not add controls in the class files, I merely hook up the signals/slots to hide/show widgets relevant to the logic in the class, within the class.

To manually add a layout to any widget you must first add at least one child widget/control. That wasn't totally clear to me and I was trying to add the layout first.