# C++ Qt QTextEdit when put in a vertical layout goes off designer window

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qdockwidget

In Qt designer, i'm trying to make a text editor so in the window I have a `QTextEdit` and a `QDockWidget` so they re size with the window I put them both in a vertical layout as a previously said and when I do they both go off the window.

The fix i'm looking for is a way to have them in a vertical layout without them going off the screen

Answer (score 0):

it seems you did not set the vertical layout as the top layout of QMainWindow, and your vertical layout does not fit into the Main widow.

Try section "Setting A Top Level Layout" in this link, http://radekp.github.io/qtmoko/api/designer-editing-mode.html. Or refer to this question [Auto-expanding layout with Qt-Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492739/auto-expanding-layout-with-qt-designer)