# How to set up self expanding widgets in Qt?

Tags: qt

I set up a user interface with a widget, and a gridlayout.
Everything works as intended until I try to ersize the window. Then the widget remains the same size, and everything looked awful.
I built up a design like this:
MainWindow
---CentralWidget
------MeasurementsWidget - QWidget
---------MeasurementsLayout - QGridLayout

I tried a lot of things but I just couldn't go through this problem.
Sometimes when I added a widget then I couldn't adjust the size of it, because it was inactive, and it resizes itself with the window. Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce this behaviour, so every thought and help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Widgets will only expand if they have a layout. You main window doesnt have a layout set for it so it will not expand. Try setting a horizontal layout for `MainWindow`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto-expanding layout with Qt-Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492739/auto-expanding-layout-with-qt-designer)