# Qt Creator expanding Layout "working area" issue

Tags: qt, pyqt

I followed the steps here: [Auto-expanding layout with Qt-Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492739/auto-expanding-layout-with-qt-designer/73324787#73324787)

I now have the issue that the "dotted area" is not expanding with the window

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set layout for your window (right click on window and select layout in bottom of context menu).

Answer (score 0):

I had to click on the central widget and change the maximum size there

Comment: That will not solve the issue. As said by Yuri, you have to set a top layout for the main widget. See [layouts in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).