# Qt: Can't set layout in QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to set my layout (using `setLayout()`) in my mainwindow. It does not show anything on launch:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0)
    {
        QVBoxLayout *vBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
        {
            QPushButton *pushButton = new QPushButton(tr("A button"));
            vBoxLayout->addWidget(pushButton);
        }
        setLayout(vBoxLayout);
    }
};
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile. You can't allocate an object of abstract type `QLayout`. See the line near the end that says `new QLayout`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to change the last two lines of code to be the following:

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
widget->setLayout(VBoxLayout);
setCentralWidget(widget);
//VBoxLayout->addWidget(new QLayout);
//setLayout(VBoxLayout);
```

The `QMainWindow` is a special case. You set the contents of this widget by putting the layout in a new `QWidget` and then setting that as the central widget.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12454012/446554) answer also.

Comment: ok thanks! why is there a setLayout void when it does nothing?

Comment: There is no `setLayout(void*)`. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setLayout. And `setLayout()` doesn't "do nothing", it sets the layout on the widget. However, if you look at the application output when running that function you should see an error saying that a layout has already been set. See the earlier documentation on `setLayout()` for an explanation of this error.

Comment: Did someone edit OPs original submission? I can't figure out which two lines to replace, and I can't figure out what the resulting code looks like. Could someone please make an additional section in the answer with the resulting answer? Sincerely.