# Qt: why adding layout to MainWindow (by code) didn't work but adding as CentralWidget worked?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qmainwindow

I have coded a `QWidget MyWidget` and I wanted to add two `MyWidget` with `QVBoxLayout` in the `MainWindow` class (the same `MainWindow` which is provided default when we open Qt Creator). So, what I did was, in the constructor of `MainWindow`, I took two pointers of `MyWidget`, make in point to an instances of the same class, then added the widgets to a `QVBoxLayout` and called `setLayout`, but when I ran the code, the ui contained nothing!

Demonstration code (didn't work):

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QLayout>
#include "mywidget.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QVBoxLayout *layout;
    layout=new QVBoxLayout();
    MyWidget *a=new MyWidget(),*b=new MyWidget();
    layout.addWidget(a);
    layout.addwidget(b);
    setLayout(layout);
}
```

But MainWindow showed nothing. Now, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12454012/1974184), I have to add layout to a widget and then set the new widget as a central widget of the `MainWindow`. I did that and that worked.

New demonstration code (Worked):

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QLayout>
#include "mywidget.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QVBoxLayout *layout;
    layout=new QVBoxLayout();
    MyWidget *a=new MyWidget(),*b=new MyWidget();
    layout.addWidget(a);
    layout.addwidget(b);
    QWidget *window=new QWidget();
    window.setLayout(layout);
    setCentralWidget(window);
}
```

My question is why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is clearly described by `QMainWindow` documentation:

> QMainWindow **has its own layout** to which you can add QToolBars,
>   QDockWidgets, a QMenuBar, and a QStatusBar. The layout has a center
>   area that can be occupied by any kind of widget.

and

> Note: Creating a main window without a central widget is not
>   supported. You must have a central widget even if it is just a
>   placeholder.